# Magento2.4: How can i display Product Admin Grid in Report Menu?

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.1, magento2.4.3, magento2.4.3.p1

I want to display the **" product grid**" from the catalog menu to in the **"Reports Menu"** in the admin panel, anyone how can I achieve this task? which means I want to access the product admin grid in the reports menu. thanks in advance.

Comment: Any hints or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by adding following line of code in

> vendor/module-reports/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

file in core module.

```
<add id="Magento_Reports::catalog_products" 
  title="Products" translate="title" 
  module="Magento_Catalog" sortOrder="90" 
  parent="Magento_Reports::report" action="catalog/product/" 
   resource="Magento_Catalog::products"/>
```

but it is a worst case because core menu.xml file couldn't be override. so we have to add custom code in core file.
just we update in custom module's menu.xml file by "update" tag

```
<menu>
    <update id="Magento_Reports::report" title="Reports" sortOrder="60" resource="Magento_Reports::report"/>
</menu>
```

I hope it would be help for you.

Comment: what if we want to display ex- like id , product name price and SKU, on our report menu grid

Comment: I mean I want to display a product admin grid In the report menu module and I only want to display product id, name and SKU like this, what approach should I follow?

Comment: i want to do this in custom module, first i have to create a menu file , then controller files and layout files something like that, but in this grid i only want to show products grid but with only some fields